# Maximization problem with SSSTriangle

Tags: maximize, ssstriangle

Recall that `SSSTriangle[a,b,c]` is the symbolic representation of a triangle with sides $a$, $b$, and $c$.  One can compute its area by (for instance):

```
Area[SSSTriangle[3,4,5]]
```

(* 6 *)

Motivated by [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4622525/find-the-maximum-area-of-a-triangle), I'd like to find the triangle with the maximum area under the constraints $0 \leq a \leq 1$, $1 \leq b \leq 2$, and $2 \leq c \leq 3$.  (Note that choosing the maximum values for all variables gives a triangle with zero area.)

This would seem to be the proper approach:

```
Maximize[
     {Area[SSSTriangle[a, b, c]], 
     0 <= a <= 1, 1 <= b <= 2, 2 <= c <= 3}, 
    {a, b, c}]
```

but *Mathematica* gives a "solution" that not only is not the maximum area, but is simply wrong:

(* {2, {a -> 0, b -> 1, c -> 3}} *)

Even `NMaximize` gives this incorrect "solution."

(Perhaps *Mathematica* is finding the longest *line*, rather than full area.)

How can one modify the syntax of the above `Maximize` to ensure the (or *a*) correct solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe add a condition that it's a valid triangle?

```
Maximize[{Area[SSSTriangle[a, b, c]], 0 <= a <= 1, 
  1 <= b <= 2, 2 <= c <= 3, a + b > c, a + c > b, b + c > a}, {a, b, 
  c}]

(* {1, {a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> Sqrt[5]}} *)
```

**Update.** Note that

```
Area[SSSTriangle[a, b, c]]
```

evaluates to

```
1/4 Sqrt[Abs[(a + b - c) (a - b + c) (-a + b + c) (a + b + c)]]
```

so without further instructions, Mathematica just maximizes the above given your boundary condition (and it's not surprising that it finds the maximum at the extremes of ranges for each variable).

Comment: Oh... of course.  Thanks so much.  ($+1$, $\checkmark$)